# Html Form save and continue later

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form in my website which uploads data to my database every time it is saved. But the problem is the form is divided by stages, and each stage is completed in different times. Is there a way to complete one stage of the form, save it, and then continue that form later (another day)?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or alternatively https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Did you consider having a unique key on the form across all stages , which could be an identifier like the user id if its a logged in user or a randomly generated session/form id if user is a guest.
When rendering the form , check in your db if a row exists for this unique key and if it does , fetch the info and progress to stage which is missing . You can also flag a stage number in the information to easily browse to that stage....
This is just one strategy , there could be many . You essentially need to check before you render the form ..

Comment: no thats completly impossible